# Need to change sharepoint date format to "dd-mmm-yyyy"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am using sharepoint 2013. I have a DOB column in dd/mm/yyyy format and want to change the same in to dd-mmm-yyyy format(eg. 01/01/2016 to 01 Jan 2016)

I have tried to change the locale under regional setting section but couldn't find dd-mmm-yyyy format in locale.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be to create a calculated field that converts the DOB to the format you want Then only display the calculated field in the list. The code would look like this:

```
=TEXT(DOB,"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

The new date will be stored as text. I'm not sure what you will need it for so I don't know that it will matter.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was just facing the same problem.  This may not be the most elegant solution, as it's very embedded, but I'm not that familiar with JSON.  Anyway, it seems to work for me in SharePoint / MS Lists.  Go to *Column Settings>Format this column* and select *Advanced Mode* so you can see the default JSON code.  Replace it with this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "span",
    "txtContent": "=getDate(@currentField)+' ' +if(getMonth(@currentField)==0,'Jan',if(getMonth(@currentField)==1,'Feb',if(getMonth(@currentField)==2,'Mar',if(getMonth(@currentField)==3,'Apr',if(getMonth(@currentField)==4,'May',if(getMonth(@currentField)==5,'Jun',if(getMonth(@currentField)==6,'Jul',if(getMonth(@currentField)==7,'Aug',if(getMonth(@currentField)==8,'Sept',if(getMonth(@currentField)==9,'Oct',if(getMonth(@currentField)==10,'Nov',if(getMonth(@currentField)==11,'Dec',' ')))))))))))) + ' ' + getYear(@currentField)"
}
```

This will show dates as 'd mmm yyyy'; i.e., you'll get '1 Jan 2023' rather than '01 Jan 2023'.  If I can figure out how to get **dd** then I'll update this.

Also:  empty values will be blank.  If you want empty values to say something like 'TBD' then you can simply insert that into the empty quotation marks that represent the 'FALSE' part of this conditional statement--like this: `...if(getMonth(@currentField)==11,'Dec','TBD')))))))))))) + ' ' + getYear(@currentField)"}`

One somewhat unrelated observation...I also found when I imported dates from Excel into SharePoint lists many dates were showing up as the day before, as if 1 day had been subtracted.  I suspect this had to do with the fact that I'm in the UK and something about our SharePoint is set to a US timezone.  I got around this by formatting my dates in Excel as numbers (so 1 Jan 2023 appears as 44927; actually this represents 12 am on 1 Jan 2023) and then adding 0.5 to all my dates (44927.5 represents 12 noon on 1 Jan 2023, i.e., one half-day later).  That way when the SharePoint gremlins did their timezone mischief and subtracted 5 or 6 hours from my value, the date didn't change.  Of course, this workaround (thanks again, Microsoft) would need to be tweaked depending where you are and how your SharePoint overlords have set things up.

Answer (score -1):

you can go to regional settings and try **English(India)** , then date format of the site will become dd-mm-yyyy